# in Spark Standalone if spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl is expired the driver workdir and its jar files are delete. is this expected?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a long running spark job. i have set the spark cleanup appDataTtl to 3 days. the job creates many tasks during its run. I see the executors create app-xxx directory in the workDir and same are deleted after the executors finish doing the task. But I see that after 3 days spark is deleting the driver-XXX directory also along with app directory. This is causing the driver to fail as it looks for the jar file in that directory. is this expected?

Comment: I came across this post from 2 years ago with no answer. Did you actually find out how to properly configure spark cleanup? I'm facing exactly the same issue with driver-XXX directory with jar being deleted.